# Hide shiny box content and keep only the header of the box shown

Tags: shiny

I am asking if is it possible to hide/show box content while the header of the box is always displayed.

Example:
`box(id = "myBox",width = 10, height = '500px', solidHeader = TRUE, status="primary",title ="Barplot",collapsible=TRUE,"Do you want to make a bar plot")`

Collapse hide the content, but i am looking to hide whole box except the header.

Thank you

Comment: please post what you have tried so far along with a reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is the default behaviour when `height = NULL`.
The height of the box is then controlled by it's content (you could e.g. set a height of 500px for your plot).

Please see the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(),
                    dashboardSidebar(),
                    dashboardBody(
                      box(
                        id = "myBox",
                        width = 10,
                        solidHeader = TRUE,
                        status = "primary",
                        title = "Barplot",
                        collapsible = TRUE,
                        "Do you want to make a bar plot"
                      )
                    ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Result]